# Asp.net core session unit test

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I hava a problem with unit testing asp.net core mvc controller!
the problem is that in my controller, i use sessions:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OpretLobby(LobbyViewModel lobby)
{
    try
    {
        //find brugeren der har lavet lobby
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<User>("user");
        //save as a lobby
        ILobby nyLobby = new Lobby(currentUser.Username)
        {
            Id = lobby.Id
        };
        SessionExtension.SetObjectAsJson(HttpContext.Session, lobby.Id, nyLobby);
        //add to the list
        _lobbyList.Add(nyLobby);
        return RedirectToAction("Lobby","Lobby",lobby);
    }
```

this all works perfectly well online on the server, nothing wrong here.
BUT when it comes to the demand of unit testing this whole thing, its not so perfect anymore.

basicly the problem is, that i cant get access to my session from a test.. i have tryed in many ways to create mocks and what not, but most of the solutions work for .net framework, and not for .net core for some reason! please help im in pain!

note:

i used a dummy version of a test to isolate this problem:

```
[Test]
public void TestIsWorking()
{
    SessionExtension.SetObjectAsJson(uut.HttpContext.Session, "user", _savedUser);
    //ViewResult result = uut.OpretLobby(lobbyViewModel) as ViewResult;

    //Assert.AreEqual("OpretLobby", result.ViewName);
    Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
}
```

goes wrong also here trying to set the session for a user :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `GetObjectFromJson` is an extension method. If so, we could not mock static method *easily*.

I normally create an abstraction for that kind of scenario. Then register it in DI container, and inject the dependency to the controller.

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddScoped<IUserSession, UserSession>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

### Abstraction

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserSession
{
    User User { get; }
}

public class UserSession : IUserSession
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserSession(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public User User => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<User>("user");
}

public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static User GetObjectFromJson<User>(
        this ISession sesson, string json) where User : new()
    {
        return new User(); // Dummy extension method just to test OP's code
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserSession _userSession;

    public HomeController(IUserSession userSession)
    {
        _userSession = userSession;
    }

    public IActionResult OpretLobby()
    {
        var currentUser = _userSession.User;
        return View(currentUser);
    }
}
```

}

### Unit Tests

```
using AspNetCore.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class HomeControllerTests
    {
        private readonly User _user;

        public HomeControllerTests()
        {
            _user = new User {Username = "johndoe"};
        }

        [Fact]
        public void OpretLobby_Test()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockUserSession = new Mock<IUserSession>();
            mockUserSession.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(_user);
            var sut = new HomeController(mockUserSession.Object);

            // Act
            var result = sut.OpretLobby();

            // Assert
            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
            var user = Assert.IsType<User>(viewResult.Model);
            Assert.Equal(_user.Username, user.Username);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Seems to go in the right direction certanly!
However in the post method of "opretLobby" is where it still go wrong, tryed like yours now, but in nunit format.
the result somehow gets to be null :/ i'll show the code

Comment: Your `OpretLobby` method returns `RedirectToActionResult`, so you need to assert as `var redirectToActionResult = Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);`. *FYI: you should not return `Model` with `RedirectToActionResult`; you could return id if you want. E.g. `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lobby), new {lobby.Id });`.*

Answer (score 2):

@nicholas-ladefoged

I would rather recommend you use integration testing when you need to get some content from session

asp.net core has an awesome `TestHost` nuget package which can help you validate logic using integration way for testing.

Try add a below code snippet

```
TestServer server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            }));
var client = server.CreateClient();

var response = await client.GetAsync(""); // I'm using GetAsync just for sample
```

here you go! You will have a real session that you can test

BTW, Moq library hasn't ability to mock a static methods, so there a lot of issues. I think that will be more easier to use an integration test in your situation

Answer (score 0):

Win solved it! Here is the final test code if anyone is wondering.

```
// Arrange
var mockUserSession = new Mock<IUserSession>();
mockUserSession.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(_savedUser);
var sut = new LobbyController(FakeSwagCommunication,mockUserSession.Object);

// Act
var result = sut.OpretLobby(_lobbyViewModel);

// Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOf<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
```